# OCaml: Leaving fields in records undefined?

Tags: ocaml, record

I have this record type:

```
type syllable = {onset: consonant list; nucleus: vowel list; coda: consonant list};;
```

What if I want to instantiate a syllable where only the nucleus is defined? Can I give it a default value? Does it default to [] or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a better idea to use "optional" fields.

```
type syllable = {onset: consonant list option; nucleus: vowel list option; coda: consonant list option};;
```

That way, you can define what you need.

```
{onset = Some [consonant, consonant, ...],
 nucleus = None,
 coda = Some [consonant, consonant, consonant, ...]}
```

I *think* that's the syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Just to make newacct's answer clearer, here's an example

```
let default_syllable = { onset = []; nucleus = []; coda = [] }

let choose_only_nucleus nucleus =
   { default_syllable with nucleus = nucleus }
```

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think you can leave things undefined. Uninitialized values cause all sorts of problems in languages like C and so it is avoided in OCaml. (Although there are a few functions in the standard library that leaves some things undefined, like `String.create`, I don't think you can do it yourself.)

You would have to either fill in all the fields yourself (and use the empty list `[]` or something like that for values you don't care about), or use a pre-existing value of this type and use the record update syntax to create a new record with the fields you care about changed, and the other ones copied over from the pre-existing record.

Comment: To expand on this, it is recommended that you either have a default structure (as unknown(yahoo) suggests), or use an option type for that particular field.